# Can more than one regression line be applied to the same sub-set of points in facet_wrap?

Tags: r, linear-regression, facet-wrap

I have a series of graphs displaying multiple sets of data per graph (one graph per treatment) and I need two different regression lines on one and only one of the data sets per graph.

Specifically, I have a set of observational data and model output attempting to reproduce that data. However, there is an outlier in the observational data that may not be legitimate. So I want one regression on the observations with all points, one without the outlier, and preferably none on the modeled data. Can this be done specifically using facet_wrap (or some other graph-collation function)? I will actually have a variable number of treatments at the different sites I'll be using this code for, so having a "smart", one-size-fits-all solution is preferred.

Here is some simplified code and output so far. So I want two lines on the Obs set and none on the Model set (though I might still accept it if that is unavoidable).

```
df <- data.frame(year=factor(c(2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,
                               2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,
                               2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,
                               2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005)),
                 treatment_code=c("T1","T1","T1","T1","T1","T1",
                                  "T1","T1","T1","T1","T1","T1",
                                  "T2","T2","T2","T2","T2","T2",
                                  "T2","T2","T2","T2","T2","T2"),
                 value=c(9,10,8.5,7.5,22,10.5,
                         11,9,12,9,10,11.5,
                         8,11,9.5,12,10,10.5,
                         7,9,11,10,12,11.5),
                 model=c("Obs","Obs","Obs","Obs","Obs","Obs",
                         "A","A","A","A","A","A",
                         "Obs","Obs","Obs","Obs","Obs","Obs",
                         "A","A","A","A","A","A"))

gS_calib <- df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=year, y=value, color=model, show.legend=TRUE)) +
  geom_point(show.legend=TRUE) +
  xlab("Year") +
  facet_wrap(~treatment_code, ncol=length(unique(df$treatment_code))) 

gS_calib
```

[image]

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but (1) you can just use `nrow = 1` instead of `ncol = length(unique(df$treatment_code))` and (2) `show.legend = TRUE` is the default, so not necessary to include.

Comment: @zephryl (1) Yes, that would work fine for this context, and (2) thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a separate dataframe for the trendlines, with data including and excluding outlier(s):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

# first change year to numeric
df <- mutate(df, year = as.numeric(as.character(year)))
 
trendlines <- df %>%
  filter(model == "Obs") %>%
  mutate(
    AllObs = value,
    OutlierRemoved = ifelse(abs(scale(value)) >= 2.5, NA, value),
    .keep = "unused"
  ) %>%
  pivot_longer(AllObs:OutlierRemoved, names_to = "fit")
 
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(year, value, color = model)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(
   data = trendlines, 
   aes(linetype = fit), 
   method = lm,
   se = FALSE
 ) +
 xlab("Year") +
 facet_wrap(~treatment_code, nrow = 1)
```

[image]