# Controlling colors using scale_color_manual with multiple data groups in legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have a follow-up question to my earlier post regarding multiple regression lines: [Can more than one regression line be applied to the same sub-set of points in facet_wrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75890927/can-more-than-one-regression-line-be-applied-to-the-same-sub-set-of-points-in-fa?noredirect=1#comment133861731_75890927)

I am struggling to get the legend to display the points, lines, and colors correctly.

There are two groups that display: Fit and Source. I want the Source to be points only with the colors I've chosen (I'm using a color-blind palette for publication). The Fit should only be lines, both black.

But if I run the code as-is, I get different colored lines through everything, including blue lines through black dots in Fit, even though the fit lines in the graph are green. If I try to tell stat-smooth to use color="black", then there are still black dots in Fit, and every line through every dot in the legend is black, Source included.

Here is code and some output:

```
output_df <- data.frame(year=c(1993,1993,1995,1995,1998,1998,2001,2001,
                               1993,1993,1995,1995,1998,1998,2001,2001),
                        treatment_scen=c("CR","CR","CR","CR","CR","CR","CR","CR",
                                         "NT","NT","NT","NT","NT","NT","NT","NT"),
                        val=c(7.16875,22.60000,23.03250,24.30000,
                              29.46125,23.60000,21.41375,24.80000,
                              9.11125,25.30000,27.13950,26.60000,
                              30.46950,24.90000,24.60500,26.10000),
                        Source=c("Observed","Model","Observed","Model",
                                 "Observed","Model","Observed","Model",
                                 "Observed","Model","Observed","Model",
                                 "Observed","Model","Observed","Model")
                        )



trendlines_df <- data.frame(year=c(1993,1993,1995,1995,
                                   1998,1998,2001,2001,
                                   1993,1993,1995,1995,
                                   1998,1998,2001,2001),
                            treatment_scen=c("CR","CR","CR","CR",
                                        "CR","CR","CR","CR",
                                        "NT","NT","NT","NT",
                                        "NT","NT","NT","NT"),
                            Fit=c("AllObs","OutlierRemoved","AllObs","OutlierRemoved",
                                  "AllObs","OutlierRemoved","AllObs","OutlierRemoved",
                                  "AllObs","OutlierRemoved","AllObs","OutlierRemoved",
                                  "AllObs","OutlierRemoved","AllObs","OutlierRemoved"),
                            value=c(7.16875,NA,23.03250,23.03250,
                                    29.46125,29.46125,21.41375,21.41375,
                                    9.11125,NA,27.13950,27.13950,
                                    30.46950,30.46950,24.60500,24.60500),
                            Source=c("Observed","Observed","Observed","Observed",
                                     "Observed","Observed","Observed","Observed",
                                     "Observed","Observed","Observed","Observed",
                                     "Observed","Observed","Observed","Observed"),
                            Model=c("Observed","Observed","Observed","Observed",
                                     "Observed","Observed","Observed","Observed",
                                     "Observed","Observed","Observed","Observed",
                                     "Observed","Observed","Observed","Observed")
)

# 9-color palette with grey and black. Colors in order are:
#[1]black, [2]dark blue, [3]green, [4]light blue, [5]grey,
#[6]pink, [7]red, [8]orange, [9]yellow
cbPalette9 <- c("#000000","#0072B2","#009E73","#56B4E9","#999999",
                "#CC79A7","#D55E00","#E69F00","#F0E442")
                                    
 
g1 <- output_df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=year, y=val, color=Source, show.legend=TRUE)) +
  geom_point(show.legend=TRUE) +
  xlab("Year") +
  stat_smooth(
    data = trendlines_df, 
    aes(linetype = Fit, y=value), 
    #color="black", 
    method = lm,
    se = FALSE,
    show.legend = TRUE,
    fullrange=TRUE
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(labels=c("Model","Observed"),
                     values=cbPalette9[c(8,3)]) +
  facet_wrap(~treatment_scen,nrow=1) 

g1
```

Here is the output with the code as-as:
[image]
Here is the output using color="black" in stat_smooth:
[image]

So how do I get Source with only points in the colors I've chosen with no lines, and Fit with only black lines and no dots?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply drop `show.legend = TRUE` from your code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

output_df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = val, color = Source)) +
  geom_point() +
  xlab("Year") +
  stat_smooth(
    data = trendlines_df,
    aes(linetype = Fit, y = value),
    color = "black",
    method = lm,
    se = FALSE,
    fullrange = TRUE
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(
    labels = c("Model", "Observed"),
    values = cbPalette9[c(8, 3)]
  ) +
  facet_wrap(~treatment_scen, nrow = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: I love easy answers - thank you so much!